# How can extract locations values from a dropdown menu that use geonames webservice for build a updated google map

Tags: google-maps, drop-down-menu, menu, geonames

I have a dropdown menu that show a list of country/state/city in a hierarchy using geonames webservice 
When i select a location in this dropdown menu it should automatically update a googlemap  in a div under this menu and zoom into that location.
How can extract locations from this dropdown menu for build a google map locations based ?
my menu code  is following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://vikku.info/programming/js/geodata-jsr-class.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var whos=null;
function getplaces(gid,src)
{   
    whos = src

//  var  request = "http://ws.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId="+gid+"&callback=getLocation&style=long";
    var request = "http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId="+gid+"&callback=listPlaces&style=long";
    aObj = new JSONscriptRequest(request);
    aObj.buildScriptTag();
    aObj.addScriptTag();    
}

function listPlaces(jData)
{
    counts = jData.geonames.length<jData.totalResultsCount ? jData.geonames.length : jData.totalResultsCount
    who = document.getElementById(whos)
    who.options.length = 0;

    if(counts)who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('Select','')
    else who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('No Data Available','NULL')

    for(var i=0;i<counts;i++)
        who.options[who.options.length] = new Option(jData.geonames[i].name,jData.geonames[i].geonameId)

    delete jData;
    jData = null        
}

window.onload = function() { getplaces(6295630,'continent'); }
</script>



<div class='main'>
<h1></h1>
<form id="myform" >
<div class="contents">
<b>*Select area</b>
<p><span>Continent:</span>  <select   name="continent" id="continent" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'country');">
<option value=""></option>                      
</select>
</p>
<p><span>Country:</span> <select name="country" id="country" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'province');">
<option value=""></option>                      
</select>
</p>
<p><span>State / Provice:</span> <select name="province" id="province" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'region')">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</p>
<p><span>County / Region:</span> <select name="region" id="region" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'city')">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</p>
<p><span>City:</span> <select name="city" id="city">
<option value=""></option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Here a working demo of menu:
http://liveweave.com/6dfhN3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geonames service provides the coordinates.  Zooming the map correctly is the tricky part.  The fiddle below uses the Google Maps Geocoder for the zoom levels (not all the geonames "names" can be found by the geocoder).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xq4h95ux/3/)

```js
var whos = null;
var placedata = [];
var map;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function getplaces(gid, src) {
    if ( !! placedata[gid]) {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lat),
            lng: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lng)
        });
        switch (src) {
            case "continent":
                map.setZoom(3);
                break;
            case "country":
                map.setZoom(5);
                break;
            case "province":
                map.setZoom(6);
                break;
            case "region":
                map.setZoom(7);
                break;
            case "city":
                map.setZoom(8);
                break;
        }
    }
    whos = src;

    var request = "http://www.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + gid + "&callback=listPlaces&style=long";
    aObj = new JSONscriptRequest(request);
    aObj.buildScriptTag();
    aObj.addScriptTag();
}

function listPlaces(jData) {
    counts = jData.geonames.length < jData.totalResultsCount ? jData.geonames.length : jData.totalResultsCount;
    who = document.getElementById(whos);
    who.options.length = 0;

    if (counts) who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('Select', '');
    else who.options[who.options.length] = new Option('No Data Available', 'NULL');

    for (var i = 0; i < counts; i++) {
        who.options[who.options.length] = new Option(jData.geonames[i].name, jData.geonames[i].geonameId);
        placedata[jData.geonames[i].geonameId] = jData.geonames[i];
    }

    delete jData;
    jData = null;
}
function zoomto(gid) {
   if ( !! placedata[gid]) {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lat),
            lng: parseFloat(placedata[gid].lng)
        });
       map.setZoom(14);
   }
}
window.onload = function () {
    getplaces(6295630, 'continent');
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {
            lat: 0,
            lng: 0
        }
    });
};
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://vikku.info/programming/js/geodata-jsr-class.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class='main'>
    
<h1></h1>

    <form id="myform">
        <div class="contents">
<b>*Select area</b>

            <p><span>Continent:</span> 
                <select name="continent" id="continent" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'country');">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><span>Country:</span> 
                <select name="country" id="country" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'province');">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><span>State / Provice:</span> 
                <select name="province" id="province" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'region')">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><span>County / Region:</span> 
                <select name="region" id="region" onchange="getplaces(this.value,'city')">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p><span>City:</span> 
                <select name="city" id="city" onchange="zoomto(this.value)">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Great you have resolved my problem Only a last request and your code is perfect In case of "No Data Available" It's possible display automatically  a empty field where users can type in  manually city and try to search it in map?

Comment: What trouble are you having doing that?

Comment: .. i should set the field on display none and set to visible when No Data Available appear

Comment: That is another question.